# ¿Qué es un piquete informativo? ¿En qué se diferencia de un piquete?

Tags: significado

Según el DLE, un [**piquete**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=T83YkJe) es:

> Grupo de personas que, pacífica o violentamente, intenta imponer o mantener una consigna de huelga.

Pero, ¿qué es un **piquete informativo**? ¿Existen también "piquetes no informativos"? La pregunta se basa en la siguiente oración que he encontrado en línea:

> Era la primera visita del menguado " piquete informativo " tres hombres y una mujer que se aventuró el jueves por los comercios del madrileño barrio de Moratalaz.
>
> <sub>El Mundo del Siglo Veintiuno (1994), extraído de la [entrada de *piquete* en Collins Spanish-English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/spanish-english/piquete)</sub>

Comment: Pude ser paquete informativo

Comment: hola Maurice para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta, seria muy utill que incluyeras las fuentes de donde extrajiste esta informacion, gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el contexto de una huelga, un [**piquete**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=T83YkJe) es (énfasis mío)

> 6. m. Grupo de personas que, **pacífica o violentamente**, intenta imponer o mantener una consigna de huelga.

En [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piquete) se aclara que

> Dado que en ocasiones los piquetes emplean métodos expeditivos, a menudo se habla de **piquetes informativos** para designar específicamente a aquellos que intentan defender el derecho de huelga de todos los trabajadores **utilizando medios legales como la información o el convencimiento**.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!